# GetDescentLine/GetAsecentLine produce different values on itextsharp and itext7

Tags: .net, itext, itext7

I am trying to port some code from **itextsharp** to **itext7**.  I was using a custom location strategy in itextsharp. I ported the code to itext7(IEventListener) . To my surprise, I found that the the Bottom and Top extents returned by **GetDescentLine** and **GetAscentLine** are different in the two versions.  I have provided a sample Visual Studio solution on Github and a sample PDF. This is a blocker because we need to move to .NET Standard/Core and itextsharp is not officially supported on Core.

Any suggestions?

**Observation - 1**
[image]

**Observation - 2**

Comparing the vertical gap between 2 consecutive sentences, using the *Bottom* of the upper sentence and the *Top* of the lower sentence. I found *itextSharp* to produce a positive gap. Using *itext7* on the same document, I get a negative gap. What does a negative gap value imply? Would it suggest a physical overlap between the 2 sentences, but visually I do not see the two sentences touching each other. 
[image]

**Code snippet - itextsharp**

```
public void RenderText_inner(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
{
    var bottomLeft = renderInfo.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
    var topRight = renderInfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();
    double x1 = bottomLeft[Vector.I1];
    double x2 = topRight[Vector.I1];
    double y1 = bottomLeft[Vector.I2];
    double y2 = topRight[Vector.I2];
    var tb = new TextBlock
    {
        Text= renderInfo.GetText(),
        Bottom=y1,
        Top=y2,
        Left=x1,
        Right=x2
    };
    Blocks.Add(tb);
}
```

**Code snippet - itext7**

```
    using (var stm = new System.IO.MemoryStream(contents))
    {
        using (var pdfReader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader(stm))
        {
            using (iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument doc = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfReader))
            {
                int numOfPages = doc.GetNumberOfPages();
                for (int page = 1; page <= numOfPages; page++)
                {
                    var pdfPage = doc.GetPage(page);
                    var pg = new Page();
                    var rotation = pdfPage.GetPageSizeWithRotation();
                    pg.Height = rotation.GetHeight();
                    pg.Width = rotation.GetWidth();
                    var customListener = new CustomEventListener();
                    var parser = new PdfCanvasProcessor(customListener);
                    parser.ProcessPageContent(pdfPage);
                    var lstBlocks = customListener.Blocks;
                    pg.Blocks = customListener.Blocks.ToArray();
                    lstPages.Add(pg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
private void RenderText_inner(TextRenderInfo textinfo)
{
    string text = textinfo.GetText();
    var bottomLeft = textinfo.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
    var topRight = textinfo.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();
    double x1 = bottomLeft.Get(Vector.I1);
    double x2 = topRight.Get(Vector.I1);
    double y1 = bottomLeft.Get(Vector.I2);
    double y2 = topRight.Get(Vector.I2);
    double fontht = textinfo.GetFontSize();
    var tb = new TextBlock
    {
        Text = textinfo.GetText(),
        Bottom = y1,
        Top = y2,
        Left = x1,
        Right = x2
    };
    Blocks.Add(tb);
```

**Github**

The complete sample is located here
https://github.com/sdg002/itext.Demo
Written using VS 2017

*Unit test method for Observation 1*
The unit test method **Fire_Both_itext5_And_itext7** will invoke class libraries written on itextsharp and itext7 . You can see the anomaly in the very first character that has been read.

*Unit test method for Observation 2*
The unit test method **Fire_Both_itext5_And_itext7_Compare_2ConsecutiveLines** will calculate the vertical gap using both the versions.

**Sample document**

https://github.com/sdg002/itext.Demo

UnitTestProject/Data/CS15.page6.pdf

**Updates**
Added Observation 2

Comment: Neither iText 5 (the .NET version of which is called iTextSharp) nor iText 7 is able to parse the glyph drawing instructions to get the precise bbox of a glyph yet. They just use different approximations to calculate that bbox. This was a conscious decision and it's not fair to expect that layout or text coordinate extraction works exactly the same after a major update. There is no "correct" behavior here, it's just different.

Comment: If you need to preserve the behavior you can parse the font information from text rendering info and have some constant multiplies for this or that font. Alternatively, you can explore how the ascend and descent line are calculated and post-process the result

Comment: Hih @AlexeySubach , Thanks for looking into this. However, I am sorry, but this does not help.   I am comparing the behavior of two consecutive versions of the product on the same test document and I would expect the API to behave consistently.  If there has been a breaking change then the change needs to be documented and communicated.

Comment: The version iText5 has reached end of line and not supported on .NET Core. So we do not have a choice but move on to iText 7. To make matters more difficult the method signatures in itext7 have changed.  Your suggestion *Alternatively, you can explore how the ascend and descent line are calculated and post-process the result* is not a feasible option. It is imperative that itText does a more thorough testing to make the end developer experience better.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I see that your expectation is that the breaking changes are communicated. I think they are. You are using `itext7` tag in your question and the description of the tag states: "_iText 7 is a complete rewrite - with a different API - of the iText library (previous version 5) for creating and manipulating PDF documents in Java and .NET._". It is stated that version 7 is a completely new library, developed from scratch. iText does thorough testing and if you refer to my first comment you would see that the behavior was changed consciously in this case.

Comment: this behavior is trash.  @Sau001 did you find a work around?